# Rethrow exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I have a very simple question about re-throwing exception in Java.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {        
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");        
}
```

Why do we need to re-throw `ex` in the first version while the second version looks more elegant? What might be the benefits and which version is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are right. Second version is better. Moreover the first version does not make any sense. It does the same except the stack trace of the exception will be "wrong".

There are the following reasons to "re-throw" exceptions:

1. If you have something to do before.
2. If you catch exception of one type and throw exception of other type:

example:

```
try {
   // do something
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ioe);
}
```

Comment: So it is more often that we do rethrow unchecked exception as wrapper instead of checked exception, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexR Agreed the first way looks odd. The stacktrace will not be 'wrong' though. The stacktrace is filled in when the exception is constructed not when it thrown. This can be seen in the source code for `java.lang.Throwable`

Comment: agreed, stack trace will be the same when you simply re-throw the Exception you just caught

Answer (score 9):

In the example given, re-throwing the `Exception` serves no purpose.

Doing this *can* be useful if the method that catches and then re-throws the exception needs to take some additional action upon seeing the `Exception`, and also desires that the `Exception` is propagated to the caller, so that the caller can see the `Exception` and also take some action.

Comment: However, typically "take some action upon seeing the exception" is better handled in a `finally{}` block.

Comment: @sleske: I disagree. `finally` is _always_ executed. So, taking @smcg's example of logging the exception: I only want that log entry in the `catch`, but not when the `Exception` doesn't happen. If it's in the `finally` I'll always get the log entry even when no `Exception` is thrown

Answer (score 8):

I would only catch/rethrow an exception (instead of just throwing it) if I wanted to do something else in the catch block - for example, write a logging statement before rethrowing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to wanting to do something with the exception before exiting - like logging, the other time you would do something like that is if you want to wrap it as a different exception, like:

```
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    throw new ServletException(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is why you think you need to rethrow the exception. Did Eclipse suggest surrounding with `try-catch`? In practice we rarely rethrow the same exception, but very often catch one and throw another that *wraps* the first one, especially if the wrapper exception is unchecked. This happens whenever you have calls declaring checked exceptions, but the method you write those calls in doesn't declare those exceptions:

```
public int findId(String name) {
  try {
    return db.select("select id from person where name=?", name);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good point.  Just keep in mind what is "checked" and "unchecked" in the context of your application.  Checked Exceptions should account for expected occasional anomalies that the application should handle.  Unchecked Exceptions are for rare, fatal faults that cannot be recovered from or necessarily even anticipated.  When rethrowing, I think that "unchecked" things should be wrapped in unchecked Exceptions, and "checked" things be wrapped in checked Exceptions.  See Oracle's "[Effective Exceptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html)."

Comment: @hotshot309 That's not quite it: every exception that means aborting the current unit of work should be unchecked and travel upwards into the common exception barrier. Only exceptions that can be recovered from *within* the unit of work, basically with an alternative processing strategy, are *candidate checked exceptions* and could also be unchecked, up to the implementor to decide. BTW **you wish** unrecoverable faults were rare; they are the norm, in fact. Of all exceptions thrown, 90% or more are unrecoverable.

Answer (score 3):

Both versions will output the same stacktrace

### without try/catch

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
//        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
//            throw ex;
//        }
    }
}
```

will output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

### with try/catch/throw same exception

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

will output exactly the same as before

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

### try/catch/throw wrapping exception

An advisable approach is to throw your own exceptions.
wrap the exception you just caught into it if you want to provide details of the root cause (might be wanted or not wanted)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("java.pdf");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while doing my process", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You can clearly see the top-level issue (my process did not complete), and the root cause that led to it (java.pdf file not found)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while doing my process
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

The flow of execution stops immediately after the `throw` statement; any subsequent statements are not executed. The nearest enclosing `try` block is inspected to see if it has a `catch` statement that matches the type of exception.

If it does find a match, control is transferred to that statement. If not, then the next enclosing `try` statement is inspected and so on. If no matching `catch` is found, then the default exception handler halts the program and prints the stack trace.

If the method is capable of causing an exception that it does not handle, it must specify this behavior so that callers of the method can guard themselves against that exception.

One can do this by including a `throws` clause in method's declaration. A `throws` clause lists the types of exceptions that a method might throw. This is necessary for all exceptions, except those of type `Error` or `RuntimeException`, or any of their subclasses. All other exceptions that a method can throw must be declared int the `throws` clause. If they are not, a compile-time error will result.