# Java: Using Catch and throws in the one block?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, try-catch, runtimeexception

What is the point of `catching` and then also `throwing` an `Exception` like below? Is it bad practice to do both?

```
  try{

    //something

    } catch (Exception e){

    throw new RuntimeException("reason for exception");
    }
```

Comment: Most people just do `e.printStackTrace()` in their catch blocks. Where did you get this/why are you throwing a new exception? The point of catching is to _prevent_ crashing, not crash the program with a completely new exception that contains none of the original information.

Comment: @Arc676 Er most people don't do `e.printStackTrace()`. In fact, I've never written this and would never recommend it: you should either log properly or rethrow.

Comment: This is normally done in cases where the method is **not** supposed to throw an exception (doesn't have any throws clause), but you still went into an unrecoverable situation that you need to terminate by throwing some exception...

Comment: I take it back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, such code is used to **re-wrap** exceptions, that means transforming the type of the exception. Typically, you do this when you are limited in what exceptions are allowed out of your method, but internally other types of exceptions can happen. For example:

```
class MyServiceImplementaiton implements MyService {
    void myService() throws MyServiceException { // cannot change the throws clause here
        try {
            .... // Do something
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // re-wrap the received IOException as MyServiceException
            throw new MyServiceException(e); 
        }
    }
}
```

This idiom enables to keep propagating exceptions to the caller, while conforming to the throws clause in the interface and hide the details of the internals (the fact that IOExceptions can happen).

In practice, this is always better than just calling `e.printStackTrace()` which will actually "swallow" the error condition and let the rest of the program run as if nothing had happened. In this respect, behaviour of Eclipse is quite bad as it tends to auto-write such bad-practice constructs if the developer is not careful.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, an `Exception` is caught and a `RuntimeException` is thrown, which effectively replaces a (potentially) checked exception with an unchecked exception that doesn't have to be handled by the caller, nor declared by the throwing method in a `throws` clause.

Some examples :

This code passes compilation :

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    try {

        //something

    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("reason for exception");
    }
}
```

This code doesn't pass compilation (assuming "something" may throw a checked exception) :

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    //something
}
```

An alternative to catching the `Exception` and throwing an unchecked exception (i.e. `RuntimeException`) is to add a `throws` clause :

```
public void SomeMethod () throws Exception
{
    //something
}
```

This is one use case of catching one type of exception and throwing another. Another use case is to catch one type of exception and throw another type of checked exception (that your method declares in its `throws` clause). It is sometimes done in order to group multiple exceptions that may be thrown inside a method, and only throw one type of exception to the caller of the method (which makes it easier for them to write the exception handling code, and makes sense if all those exceptions should be handled in the same manner).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I don't understand why this is preffered to just throwing the original exception? I.e. throwing Exception, rather than RuntimeException?

Comment: You cannot always throw a checked exception. That has to become part of your method signature, and that may not be possible (because of inheritance for example). You can always throw unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException).

Answer (score 0):

This is called *rethrowing an exception*, and it is a common pattern.

It allows you to change the class of the exception (such as in this case), or to add more information (also the case here, as long as that error string is meaningful).

It is often a good idea to attach the original exception:

```
throw new RuntimeException("cause of the problem", e);
```

Rethrowing as an unchecked exception (a RuntimeException) is sometimes necessary when you still want to throw an exception, but the API of your method does not allow a checked exception.

Comment: I think "rethrowing" an exception is doing `throw e;`... The OP is just creating a new exception (from catch block)...

Comment: @Codebender: I'd also include this pattern. Catch an exception, throw an exception back. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11972811/14955, too

Comment: Thank you, What is happening "under the hood" when a method is re-thrown? I don't understand the concept?

Comment: Nothing special really. Just a "normal" catch and a "normal" throw operation. The effect is that you still propagate an exception, but you get to "shape it" as you see fit.