# Getting compilation error in main even though try catch finally block is added in the calling method

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to run the below code but getting compilaton error as "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException", as per my understanding this should not happen since try catch and finally blocks are added in the calling method.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myMethod();
    }

    public static void myMethod() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("In the try block");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("in the catch block");
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("in the finally block");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're rethrowing the exception, so you're left with an unhandled exception.

Comment: Simplest solution: Just add `throws FileNotFoundException` to `main()`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `throws FileNotFoundException` from the `myMethod` signature (and then you'll need to remove `throw e;` from the `catch` block).

**Or**, add a `try` and `catch` to your `main` method (to handle the `FileNotFoundException` that you have indicated `myMethod` **can** throw).

**Or**, add `throws FileNotFoundException` to the signature of `main` (as pointed out by Andreas in the comments).

In short, the compiler will not allow you to have a code path with checked exceptions that are not handled.

Comment: Thanks, so it was the issue of re-throwing exception which was already caught.

Comment: Not exactly.  It is the issue that you declared your `myMethod()` to throw `FileNotFoundException`.  As long as you declared your method like that, even you are not rethrowing in your catch block of `myMethod`, you still need to catch in your `main`

Comment: Why not just add `throws FileNotFoundException` to `main()`? No need to add code to `catch` and print stacktrace in `main()`, since Java will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `catch` block, you are throwing the `Exception` again once you catch it. If you really want to throw it from the `myMethod()` even after catch it, just add another try-catch to the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        myMethod();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("catch block in main");
    }
}
```

Or else if you want to just catch the `Exception` in your `myMethod()`, don't throw it back.

```
try{
    System.out.println("In the try block");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("in the catch block");
}
finally{
    System.out.println("in the finally block");
}
```

you can read more about re-throwing exceptions in following question.

[Rethrow exception in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972765/rethrow-exception-in-java)