# Handling exceptions from methods in map of Optional

Tags: java, option-type

I have a method like this.

```
@Override
public Optional<List<Order>> getPendingOrders(AuthDTO authDTO) throws MyException {
    return connector.getConnection(authDTO).map(p->p.getOrders());
}
```

Here

```
connector.getConnection(authDTO)
```

returns an Optional of Connection and

```
p->p.getOrders()
```

throws KException which I cannot change and is of the form

```
public class KException extends Throwable {

    // variables
    public String message;
    public int code;

    // constructor that sets the message
    public KException(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    // constructor that sets the message and code
    public KException(String message, int code){
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

and this the strucute of MyException

```
public class MyException extends KException {

    public MyException(String message, int code) {
        super(message, code);
    }
}
```

The code is not compiling with the below error

```
unreported exception com.something.exceptions.KException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I want to convert this KException to MyException. Is there are an elegant way to do this? PLease help.

Comment: Why aren't you throwing `KException`?

Comment: You can convert it only if it's extending MyException.

Comment: Just throw a new exception like done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972765/rethrow-exception-in-java

Comment: KException is from an External library. I have various handlers and logic on MyException.

Comment: ...and you can't extend `KException`?

Comment: wrap your `return` statement in `try-catch` and throw whatever you need.

Comment: it already extends it. Updated the question

Comment: Tried it. Wrapping return in try catch doesn't work as p->p.getOrders()  throws the exception which should be handled first.

Comment: catch(KException e){ throw new MyException(e.message, e.code);}?

Comment: What does it mean to return an empty `Optional<List<Order>>`? Would it really have a different meaning from an empty `List<Order>`? You should avoid wrapping collections into optionals (and vice versa), as this is quite cumbersome to use for the caller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception)

Comment: Also [Java 8: Mandatory checked exceptions handling in lambda expressions. Why mandatory, not optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039995/java-8-mandatory-checked-exceptions-handling-in-lambda-expressions-why-mandato)

Comment: `Optional` and lambdas are a poor fit here.

Comment: This is pretty much the same issue as with your other question from yesterday: [Handling exceptions while returning values by Optional flatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661370/handling-exceptions-while-returning-values-by-optional-flatmap). The solutions are similar: catch KException in the lambda, re-throw as RuntimeException, catch that one outside the lamba, re-throw as MyException.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by some of the comments, you can trap the exception within the `map` operation and then perform any further logic you need to do:

```
return getConnection(authDTO).map(p -> {
        try {
            return p.getOrders();
        } catch (KException e) {
            // perform some other logic
        }
});
```

Comment: From what I'm reading of the OP's requirements, `Order::getOrders` is likely to throw an exception.  Strange, but that has nothing to do with the optional or any resultant throw (because by the time you bother throwing from the call `getOrders`, *another* exception's already been thrown).

Answer (score -3):

Cant you just do like this?

```
@Override
public Optional<List<Order>> getPendingOrders(AuthDTO authDTO) throws MyException {
    return connector.getConnection(authDTO)
            .map(p->p.getOrders())
            .orElseThrow(MyException::new));
            
}
```

Comment: `orElseThrow` will execute if the `map` function returns empty, I don't think it will catch an exception thrown in `map`. [ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)